# Duplicate entry for primary key on abstract class

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a class Employee which extends Person. When I try to save a Employee I am getting an error about duplicate id (Unit Test).

Environment:
Hibernate 6.2
Spring Boot 3.2
Java 18

My classes:

**Person**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Data
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table(name="PERSON")
public abstract class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long personId;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    private Check check;
}
```

And

**Employee**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee extends Person {

@Column(unique = true)
private String empCode;

@JoinColumn(name ="dateA")
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate dateA;

@Lob
private String comment;

public Pit(String empCode, LocalDate dateA, String comment) {
    this.empCode = empCode;
    this.dateA = dateA;
    this.comment = comment;
   }
}
```

I try to instantiate a instance of Employee

`Employee emp = employeeRepository.save(new Employee("XRY827", LocalDate.of(2023, 03, 28), "comment"));`

But I get :

```
could not execute statement [Duplicate entry '1' for key 'employee.PRIMARY'] [insert into employee (check_id,code,comment,date_a,person_id) values (?,?,?,?,?)]; SQL [insert into employee (check_id,code,comment,date_inserted,person_id) values (?,?,?,?,?)]; constraint [employee.PRIMARY]
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement [Duplicate entry '1' for key 'employee.PRIMARY'] [insert into employee(check_id,code,comment,date_inserted,person_id) values (?,?,?,?,?)]; SQL [insert into employee (check_id,code,comment,date_inserted,person_id) values (?,?,?,?,?)]; constraint [employee.PRIMARY]
```

From the SQL in the error above it looks like hibernate is trying to insert a `person_id` and a `check_id` - even though the `check_id` is optional and the `person_id` is generated?

How can I create a new Employee without error?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you provided indicates that you're encountering a duplicate key violation in the "employee" table's primary key field. This means that you're trying to insert a record with a value for the primary key column that already exists in the table.

The error message specifically mentions "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'employee.PRIMARY'", which indicates that you're trying to insert a record with a value of '1' in the primary key column, but there is already a record with that value in the table.

To resolve this issue:

1. **Check Data**: Review the data you're inserting and ensure that you're not inserting duplicate values for the primary key column.
2. **Primary Key Sequence**: If the primary key is generated by a sequence or an auto-increment feature, make sure that you're not manually specifying the primary key value while inserting the record.
3. **Database State**: Check the current state of the "employee" table to verify if there's already a record with the primary key value you're trying to insert.
4. **Unique Constraint**: Ensure that the primary key column has a unique constraint defined and that there are no data integrity issues in the table.
5. **Data Insertion Logic**: Double-check your code logic for inserting data into the "employee" table to make sure there are no unintended duplicate insertions.

By addressing these points, you should be able to resolve the duplicate key violation issue and successfully insert records into the "employee" table without encountering the constraint violation.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long personId;
```

it will be ok

Answer (score 0):

The issue is to do with key generation and related to `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` being used with `IDENTITY` generation strategy for Id from Hibernate.

The `SEQUENCE` generation strategy is preferred and better for hibernate since it tracks the Id generation rather than the database being responsible for it.